# How to add HTML data with double quotes to a String in java?

Tags: android

```
String s=
    "<html>
    <head>
    <title>app</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="pink">
    <div align="center"><img src="" width="900" height="100"/>
    </div>
    <h2 align="center">Welcome to your rewards program</h2>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td><p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;You now  have ongoing uninterrupted access to thousands of discounts all on your phone .Accessing great  savings just got so easier . You can search by category , by keyword and also search local with what around me. Select a merchant offer you like and present the coupon on your phone  at the time of settling your bill .  Some merchants only offer their services online and you will also be able  to click through to their online offerings . 
    GIN image</p></td>
    </tr>

    </table>
    </body>
    </html>";
```

I want to add the html data to the string,but it is giving me errors.How can I solve this?
I used the escapse sequences but it didnt worked.

thanks

Comment: Can you use [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) from apache ?

Comment: you cant have open multiline strings in java. you have to concat them with + and escape the " of course

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
String s=
            "<html>"+
            "<head>"+
            "<title>app</title>"+
            "</head>"+
            "<body bgcolor=\"pink\">"+
            "<div align=\"center\"><img src=\"\" width=\"900\" height=\"100\"/>"+
            "</div>"+
            "<h2 align=\"center\">Welcome to your rewards program</h2>"+
            "<table>"+
            "<tr>"+
            "<td><p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;You now  have ongoing uninterrupted access to thousands of discounts all on your phone .Accessing great  savings just got so easier . You can search by category , by keyword and also search local with what around me. Select a merchant offer you like and present the coupon on your phone  at the time of settling your bill .  Some merchants only offer their services online and you will also be able  to click through to their online offerings ."+ 
            "GIN image</p></td>"+
            "</tr>"+
            "</table>"+
            "</body>"+
            "</html>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String s=
        "<html>"
        + "<head>"
        + "<title>app</title>"
        + "</head>"
        + "<body bgcolor=\"pink\">"
        + "<div align=\"center\"><img src=\"\" width=\"900\" height=\"100\"/>"
        + "</div>"
        + "<h2 align=\"center\">Welcome to your rewards program</h2>"
        + "<table>"
        + "<tr>"
        + "<td><p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;You now  have ongoing uninterrupted access to thousands of discounts all on your phone." 
        + " Accessing great  savings just got so easier . You can search by category , by keyword and also search local with what around me. Select a merchant offer you like and present the coupon on your phone  at the time of settling your bill." 
        + " Some merchants only offer their services online and you will also be able  to click through to their online offerings ." 
        + " GIN image</p></td>"
        + "</tr>"
        + "</table>"
        + "</body>"
        + "</html>";
```

Comment: in the above code whole string will be a single line to format it add a +"\n" to each line

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse IDE...

Eclipse won't support multiline string assignment.

If you are using eclipse editor then goto 
`Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Typing`
and chack `Escape text when pasting into a string literal`

After that you can copy entire string value and past it once again.